# Is it safe to use "{{ field(class=...) }}" in Jinja2?

Tags: python, jinja2, wtforms

I'm using Flask/Wtforms/Jinja2 and I'm not sure if I understand this section from the `WTforms` correctly :

> If one wants to pass the “class” argument which is a reserved keyword
>   in some python-based templating languages, one can do:
>
> `form.field(class_="text_blob")`

It's clear that `form.field(class_="text_blob")` is safe to use in a template. However `form.field(class="text_blob")` works for me fine.

Does it mean that `class` is not reserved in Jinja2 and I do not need to care? Or should I correct all `class=` to `class_=` to prevent possible problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct, `class` is not a reserved word in Jinja. It can still be used as a keyword argument from `**kwargs` in Python, it just can't be written in code. This is how WTForms supports both spellings.

```
form.field(**{'class': 'text_blob'})
```